# Embed a contact form

Tags: forms, 8, emails

Is it possible to take a contact form and embed it into a page.html.twig or node.html.twig file? Or is the form only accessible via its contact/machine_name link?

Comment: I would like to refer to a new main D8 question to help with all sub-questions like this here, caused by the open basic question, well documented here in details: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/197149/updated-da-drupal-8-0-5-rendering-forms-entities-programmatically-on-theming

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out [Contact Storage](http://drupal.org/project/issues/contact_storage).

Among various other features, like being able to store contact messsages, the latest version has a view builder that allows to display a referenced contact form (it's a config entity, so you can reference it using a standard entity reference field).

Comment: I would like to refer to a new main D8 question to help with all sub-questions like this here, caused by the open basic question, well documented here in details: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/197149/updated-da-drupal-8-0-5-rendering-forms-entities-programmatically-on-theming

Comment: And while this is a *solution*, it is actually not an answer regarding the exact question, but something tells me I shouldn't be too picky today ;-)

Comment: Detailed info: https://www.peacog.com/drupal-blog/placing-contact-form-block-drupal-8

Comment: Alternatives: lightweight https://www.drupal.org/project/contact_block, generic solutions are https://www.drupal.org/project/entityform_block and https://www.drupal.org/project/formblock